# Is toString() defined to return this for a java.lang.String?

Tags: java, language-lawyer

Consider

```
String foo = s.toString();
```

for a non-`null` `java.lang.String` instance `s`.

Is this defined to return itself, or is it up to a particular Java implementation? Out of interest is a "deep copy" taken?

Examining my source code of my JDK affirms that `s` is returned, but does the JLS insist on that? I've been brought up to regard `toString()` as an arbitrary serialisation, perhaps representative of the object, but not necessarily so. For example, it's entirely plausible (in my opinion at least) that an implementation could surround the string in quotation characters.

Comment: `toString()` returns a `String` representation of an `Object`. What `String` would better represent a `String` `Object` than itself ?

Comment: Indeed, that's a rational way to think, but language specifications are not necessarily rational.

Comment: What do you mean by *deep copy*? Behavior of `toString` is not explicitly defined for `String` in JLS (but it is kind of apparent, that it should return itself). However string memory manipulation is something which I would expect to be in JLS or JVM spec... and as String is immutable it would not make sense to make any copies.

Comment: It's probably moot as strings are immutable, but a deep copy means that the memory for the returned string is entirely disjoint to the original one.

Comment: Note that it is probably not in the scope of JLS, to give implementation details of overriden methods.

Comment: @Berger: Normally, I would agree that this is a JRE matter not a JLS matter, but both the JVMS and the JLS *do* mention `java.lang.String` AFAIR, so it *could* be there. (I believe the JLS also depends on `toString()` as well.)

Comment: For the surround-with-quotation-marks part: while default [Object.toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) really returns type information, whenever a toString can return an actual stringified value, it does not provide a type-hint.

Answer (score 23):

You wouldn't find any guarantee in the JLS but you do have one in [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toString--):

> This object (which is already a string!) is itself returned.

Comment: So it's not possible for a JDK to do anything else, such as enclosing the string in quotation characters?

Comment: @P45Imminent But why you are expecting to do that ?

Comment: Because it's reasonable behaviour. Less reasonable than returning the string as-is, but still reasonable.

Comment: @P45Imminent Updated my answer. My whole point here is there is no good reason to make a new copy.

Comment: @P45Imminent So you expect `"a".toString().toString().toString().equals("\"\"\"a\"\"\"")` to be valid? Sorry but that makes very little sense.

Comment: @corsiKa I believe he is questioning whether, given a string `str`, if it is possible for `str==str.toString()` to be false.

Answer (score 20):

It returns itself

```
 /**
     * This object (which is already a string!) is itself returned.
     *
     * @return  the string itself.
     */
    public String toString() {
        return this;
    }
```

Looking at [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java) you can easily find this out.

I'm sure that we can't find Java language specification for each method's implementation. Just like any other Java class `toString()` method of String class just Returns a string representation of it's  own.

**Update :**

Since your actual question is about why it is returning it self rather than a copy or some hack like quotes to make a new String, I'll slightly disagree on that. My reasons for the same (*may be there are other good reasons than this*) since you are invoking `toString()` method on actual string instance (`s`) itself, I see no harm here. If you want to play around you'll do that with `s` instance directly anyway.

Comment: Indeed I did that, but does the JLS *insist* on that?

Comment: @ANS The JavaDoc makes guarantees that **every** JDK implementation has to adhere to. The source code is just an implementation detail. The JavaDoc is the contract that must be upheld. That is true for every single piece of software btw. Source code is just a detail that can (and in most cases probably will) change some time.

Comment: For the `Why it is returning it self rather than a copy or some hack like quotes to make a new String`, I think it's perfectly safe to return `this` in the String class because String objects are immutable.

Comment: @ANS: Which source code? Oracle JDK's? Oracle JRockit's? IBM J9 JDK's? IcedTea's? Apache Harmony's? GNU Classpath's? Excelsior JET's?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Ahh I see your point (*pointing different implementation of JLS*). I mean just in this case as I couldn't find anything about `String#toString` in JLS

Comment: @ANS: It used to be in the JLS in v1.0 (and, BTW, had very similar wording even back then), but they've since outsourced the library specifications to the class library docs.

Comment: I don't believe this answers the question.  OP clearly said that he/she has already looked at the JDK source code and seen that `toString` _does_ return `this`, but the question is whether the JLS requires it to.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem OP edited the question later I posted the answer. And he asked several question in other comments, I believe addressed them. Regarding JLS, I already said that there is not clue about toString in JLS, all we have is official oracle docs to go with. Pure JLS, no.

Answer (score 20):

Yes. See [Java Language Specification §1.4 – Relationship to Predefined Classes and Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-1.html#jls-1.4):

> As noted above, this specification often refers to classes of the Java SE platform API. In particular, some classes have a special relationship with the Java programming language. Examples include classes such as `Object`, `Class`, `ClassLoader`, `String`, `Thread`, and the classes and interfaces in package `java.lang.reflect`, among others. This specification constrains the behavior of such classes and interfaces, but does not provide a complete specification for them. **The reader is referred to the Java SE platform API documentation.**

So the javadoc of those classes (which is the "Java SE platform API documentation") is normative and part of the overall language spec. And that [states explicitly](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toString--):

> `public String toString()`
>
> This object (which is already a string!) is itself returned.

There's no room for interpretation.

(It would break countless programs if they changed it to do anything different anyway.)

Comment: This is (so far) the best answer here, and the only one which deals with the question completely.  The important point is that the JLS defers to the Javadoc for the required features of certain classes.